# Proxy object in Vue 3 will not let me access data

Tags: javascript, object, proxy, components, vuejs3

I have an app in Vue 3 where I make a call to the back end of my code to get data. The data is returned nested in JSON arrays and objects, and I then assign the data to a property in my component. I am trying to assign the JSON object to data in my parent component and then pass the data as a prop to my child component. However, every time I do this, the data keeps getting assigned as `Proxy(Object)` which seems to make it more difficult to access the data in the child component.

My code is as follows:

```
/* Parent Component */
<template>
  <div>
    <child-component :myData="rawData"></child-component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent.vue';
  export default {
    components: {
      ChildComponent
    },
    data() {
      return {
        rawData: {}
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getData() {
        fetch('/my-endpoint, { method: 'GET' })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            this.rawData = data[0].data[0];
          })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

```
/* Child Component */
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      myData: {
        type: Object
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        displayData: myData
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I try to `console.log()` any of the data that holds my `fetch` call (`rawData`, `myData` or `displayData`) I'm seeing `Proxy (Object)` in the console, and I can't access any of the data in the object. I see the data in the Vue dev tools plugin, but I cannot use any of it. Even trying to do something like `console.log(displayData.id)` or `console.log(displayData.description)`, which are properties I know exist in these objects and properties I see in the Vue dev tools plugin, I just get `undefined` in the console.

**What I have tried to do:**

- `import { isProxy, toRaw } from 'vue';` in both the parent and child components and then `if(isProxy(myData)) toRaw(myData);` (and the same with `rawData` and `displayData`). This does not work and the objects are still proxies.
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData));` in both the parent and child components (and the same with `rawData` and `displayData`). This does not work and the objects are still proxies.
- Out of desperation, changing the prop declaration in the child component to just `props: { myData: Object }` and even just `props: ['myData']`. This does not work and the objects are still proxies.

How can I access the data in these objects? I'd prefer for them to not be proxy objects, but if I cannot change them then how do I get data if they need to stay as proxies?

Comment: The proxy wrapper is a feature, not a bug. It enables Vue's reactivity. Please update the question to include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Vue's reactivity is neither a problem, nor an error.

Comment: @tao nowhere in my question did I mention that the proxy wrapper was a bug, a problem or an error. As a matter of fact, your responses are stating these words, not mine. The last two sentences in my question were specific and clear - if you re-read, you'll see exactly what I am asking.

Comment: You implicitly stated it's a problem or an error when you asked the question. By definition, in order to be on topic, a [SO] question has to present *"a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"*. Please read [ask] and its afferent links. This question's problem (or at least part of it) is inferred from *"I'd prefer them not to be proxy objects"*. But let's leave semantics aside. Regardless of how we name it, what are you searching for? What do you want to achieve? Because right now, that's not quite clear, making your question borderline *off-topic*.

Comment: Yes, I am having a problem because I cannot access my data. Not being able to access my data doesn't mean that I am stating the proxy wrapper itself is a bug or an error. I never stated what you initially stated, which was that the proxy wrapper is a "bug", "problem" or "error". In terms of what I am searching for, and/or what I want to achieve - this was again stated in the last two sentences of my original question. I'm not sure what is unclear, and copying/pasting it here is redundant. If you do not understand the question or how to solve my issue, you're not obligated to comment.

Comment: Where: in my child component. How: as a data property in a form in the child component.

After passing data from my `getData()` function in my parent component to my child component as a prop, the data is inaccessible in `console.log()`. I'd like to use the data in a data property for `v-model`, which I've also tried and also comes up as `undefined`. If I put the data in a computed property, then it seems to work but then it is immutable.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few things that need to be fixed:

**Parent component:**

- When dealing with async calls, it's recommended to use the `v-if` directive to avoid errors and UI bugs.
- Invoke the getData() method in either the created() or mounted() lifecycle hook, depending on your specific use case.

**Child Component:**

- When using the options API in Vue, make sure to wrap the component with `export default {}`.
- The `data()` method should be a function that returns an object. It should look like this: `data() { return {} }`.
- Use the keyword `this` when necessary to access component properties and methods.

Here's the corrected code. Please note that since I don't have your endpoint, I used JokeAPI as an example:

```
/* Parent Component */
<template>
  <div v-if="rawData">
    <child-component :myData="rawData" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ChildComponent from "../components/ChildComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "ParentComponent",
  components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rawData: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    // or mounted() - read docs to see the difference and choose accordingly
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      // example with JokeAPI
      fetch("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any", { method: "GET" })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.rawData = data;
          // uncomment the next line according to your data
          // this.rawData = data[0].data[0];
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>
      {{ displayData }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    myData: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return { displayData: this.myData };
  },
};
</script>
```

And here is the codesandbox for you to test and play: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-sound-46wiud)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I modified my code to ask the question and just forgot to include the `export default` and `data() { return {...} }` code in my example, but those are in my original code. I added the `v-if` in my code but that did not solve my issue.

Any idea how to change the proxy object to just a regular JSON object, or how to get data out of a proxy object?

Comment: Maybe you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(<your-proxy-data>))` but it is not recommended. You mostly shouldn't break reactivity but it's hard to decide witout your full code...